# AppBar button style

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

In Windows Store Apps there are the `AppBarButtonStyle`s to get a nice round button like the ones mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj841127.aspx).

Is there a simple way to get those styles for WP7?

I found some tutorials on the net ([like this](https://nirmitk26.blogspot.com/2011/02/round-button-in-windows-phone-7.html)), and 3rd party libraries (e.g. http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) but it feels like there should be a standard simple way of doing that without getting to complex. Is there?

Comment: are you looking for a convenient way to get a) round buttons b) the icons for the button or c) both?

Comment: Just a) would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The [RoundButton](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RoundButton&referringTitle=Documentation) from the [Coding4Fun Toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com) will do the job just fine. There is currently no built-in component like that in the Windows Phone SDK.

Also, remember that the way the AppBar operates in Windows Store and Windows Phone 8 apps is different **at the core**, so the same interaction and building ideas don't exactly apply.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Den. I think your opinion about Coding4Fun Toolkit could be biased though, as you work for Coding4Fun. ;) However, I decided to go with a custom button style as the RoundButton didn't scale well.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly doesn't scale well? We're always looking to improve the toolkit.

Comment: @DenDelimarsky I have a scaling issue which I cannot find a solution to in the codeplex docs, stackoverflow, geekchamp articles, etc. I have posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234531/setting-imagesource-in-coding4fun-roundbutton-not-scaling if you could please take a look? Adding Windows Phone 8 icons as the ImageSource do not scale to look like the appbar buttons, the images are way too big in the border circle.