# Setting ImageSource in Coding4Fun RoundButton Not Scaling

Tags: c#, image, xaml, button, windows-phone-8

I am trying to create a button that is the exact same look and feel as a regular Windows Phone 8 application bar button. I am using the Coding4Fun RoundButton for this. My issue is that when setting the ImageSource I cannot get the image to scale to fit inside of the button properly, it is far too big. I am using a standard application bar icon image from the Windows Phone 8 SDK, whch is 76x76. I've also resized to mimic the Windows Phone 7 icon size of 48x48 but the same result occurs. How can I adjust the image so it fits in the RoundButton properly?

XAML

```
<c4f:RoundButton x:Name="browseRoundButton" Click="Browse_Click"/>
```

XAML.CS

```
if (Settings.LightTheme.Value)
    browseRoundButton.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Icons/feature.search.light.png", UriKind.Relative));     
else
    browseRoundButton.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Icons/feature.search.dark.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

EDIT* In referencing sources like http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-roundtogglebutton-and-roundbutton-in-depth and http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/discussions?searchText=roundbutton I cannot seem to find any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to set the ImageSource in the XAML (using only the dark style icon) and ensure the size is 48x48. Works Great!